# arm neon - divide 32x4x2 into two 32x4

Tags: arm, neon

I'm new to Arm and Neon.

I wanna divide int32x4x2_t A into two int32x4_t B1,  int32x4_t B2.

So, if A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8], I want to make B1 to [1 2 3 4] and B2 to [5 6 7 8]

I tried

```
B1 = vld1q_s32(A);
B2 = vld1q_s32(A+4);
```

But it does not work.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int32x4x2_t` is really just a struct that looks like

```c
typedef struct int32x4x2_t {
  int32x4_t val[2];
} int32x4x2_t;
```

So all you have to do is

```c
B1 = A.val[0];
B2 = A.val[1];
```